# How to run many scripts python successively?

Tags: python, time, cmd, operating-system

I have 3  different python scripts, each script has an output which is the input of  the following script. I tried to use time but it's not working for all the projects. Any help please !

This is what I tried:

```
script1:
......
time.sleep(60)

script2:
......
time.sleep(60)

script3:
......
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: google "python scheduler"

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `os.stdout` and `os.stdin` check result of each script.